# Neglect a pattern using Regex

Tags: swift, regex, swift5

I need help to neglect a pattern while searching substring using regex. 
For example, in below string

`Hello *testing [*_*] message* text`  or

`Hello *testing [_*_*] message* text * additional* message`  or

`Hello testing [*_*_] message* text * additional* message*`  or

```
Hello testing [_*_*_] message* text * additional* message*
```

I need to find out all * to replace with html bold tag, except those which comes within square brackets '[]'. 
But when I run this regex `[*]((?s).*?)[*]`, It also include * within [], and replace those as well. How can I ignore `[*` and `*]` combination while this search.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Basically I wanted to ignore matching for given character (eg `*`) if it is within square brackets `[` and `]`.

Comment: Can you use negative lookarounds?  If so, something like `'(?<!\[)\*(?!])'` will match the `*` unless it is preceded or followed by a `[` or `]`

Comment: A state machine might give better results here

Comment: @Cristik In practice it would be probably easier to implement and debug. However, note that finite state machines are equivalent to regular expressions.

Comment: @Sulthan I think it's the other way around: regular expression parsers use state machines. Also, not sure how easy would it be to write a correct regex for this case, this is why I recommended a custom parser\

Comment: Is this really for swift or is it a general regex question?

Comment: it is general, but I am using it in swift.

Comment: Well you should makes sure it works for the flavour of regex that swift uses, [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) if swift is your target language.

Answer (score 1):

What about pattern `(\s+\*)|(\*\s+)`, it matches `*` plus any number of spaces after or before it.

*Edit*

`(\*\s*\w*\s*\*)|(\*\s*\w*\s*\[\*.*\*\]\s*\w*\s*\*)`

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/PyOPSf/4)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my requirement is to get value within pair of * ignoring * within [].  So for above message in my question should give value  with first and last *.

Comment: @Surjeet it does ignore `[*_*]` giving you 2 match groups containing first and last * in the string

Comment: Yes, It does. But I need a group containing substring within * as value.  Also this will not work if space is not there before/after *

Comment: If you run regex in my question, It give me value, which I want, except I am not able to ignore  `[*_*]`

Comment: @Surjeet ok I got you try to figure it out if I can

Comment: @Surjeet what about simply `[*](.*)[*]`

Comment: Above regex will consider only first and last * and will return value within that. This case fails if multiple set of * are there in string. Ex:  `Hello *testing [*_*] message* text * additional* message`. This string should return two groups. 1st group should be `testing [*_*] message` and another should be  `additional`.

Comment: @Surjeet another try `(\*\s*\w*\s*\*)|(\*\s*\w*\s*\[\*.*\*\]\s*\w*\s*\*)` https://regex101.com/r/PyOPSf/4

Comment: Currently, I am away from my system, will respond after try.

Comment: Hey @schmidt9, updated regex doesn't work if I have updated input strings. I have updated my question with some test string

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(?<!\[)\*(?!\])(.*?)(?<!\[)\*(?!\])` -although bit ugly- does what you really want in the comments.

For the string `Hello *testing [*_*] message* text * additional* message` 
it returns `testing [*_*] message, additional`

The `(?<!\[)\*(?!\])` part only matches with a *valid* "*"

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/uN0tQb/1) is how it works.

Comment: Currently, I am away from my system, will respond after try.

Comment: Hi @xcan, It works great for the scenario, I have described in given string, and return return result as expected. But failed in one scenario, when put one or more characters between `[` and `*` or `*` and `]`.

Comment: Basically I wanted to ignore given character for ex `*` if it is between `[` and `]` regardless of its position within square brackets. I have put some cases here https://regex101.com/r/uN0tQb/2

Comment: Hello @Surjeet, i used negative lookahead & lookbehind for this regex. Any kind of look ahead needs fixed sized characters. I don't think what you want can be done with a single regex or at least any single regex i can write. I suggest that you should do some preprocessing before using regex or write a custom parser for this.

Comment: For example extract "[]" put a special index for them, use the regex i gave then re insert them all. `Hello *testing [*_*] message* text *some [_*_*] additional* text` -> `Hello *testing $%1 message* text *some $%2 additional* text` -> regex i gave->`Hello <b>testing $%1 message<\b> text <b>some $%2 additional<\b> text `->re-insert -> `Hello <b>testing [*_*] message<\b> text <b>some [_*_*] additional<\b>`

Answer (score 0):

You could match what you don't want and keep the asterix in a capturing group  using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

The in the replacement, wrap the value of the first capturing group in a html bold tag

```
\[[^*\]]*\*[^\]]*\]|(\*)
```

That will match:

- `\[[^*\]]*\*[^\]]*\]` Match `[` ... `]` with an `*` in between using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^`
- `|` Or
- `(\*)` Capture group 1, match an asterix

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kEauMm/1)

Or use the shorter version which will not account for matching an asterix but matches from an opening till a closing square bracket

```
\[[^\]]+\]|(\*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RtdJE4/1)

Comment: It doesn't ignored * when inside square brackets.

Comment: @Surjeet I have not experience in swift, but you could check using the code if you have a value in capturing group 1. If that is the case, return group 1 wrapped in html bold tags. If there is no value, return only the match. Perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005749/ios-nsregularexpression-with-conditional-piece-of-template) can be helpful.